# LC-3: Conditional Statement for Input Values

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, lc3

I have a problem where I am supposed to take user input (as TRAP x23), but only certain user inputs. Basically, my problem would look like such in pseudo:

`if value <= 5 & value >=0 
 print yes
 else
 print error`

I also need to account for when someone types in a non-numerical character, and I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LC-3 you are can only do comparisons with 0. You can test if the last value saved in register was negative, zero, or positive. So you will need to rewrite these statements in terms of a comparison with 0 and the if statement will need to be broken up into 2.

A more easily translatable version of your pseudocode would look like the following

`if value-5 > 0 goto PRINT_ERROR
 if value < 0 goto PRINT_ERROR
 ; print yes`

These more easily translate to BR statements if any of the if statements evaluates to true then you jump to a label with code that handles printing your error message.  If none of them are taken then you print yes afterward you can do whatever you want.